# Why with history.push onClick function I have two components rendered insted of one which I wanted?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a situation where on onClick funtion which should push to path :'/trains/alerts-list' which actually happens but it renders under this url component TrainAlertsList which is correct, but below it's rendering also TrainDetailsScreen which is not correct.
I have onClick function like below :

[image]

Which creates url path of TrainsListAlerts:

```
TrainsAlertsList: {
        path: '/trains/alerts-list',
        name: 'Trains alerts list',
        viewName: 'TRAINS_ALERTS_LIST',
    },
TrainDetails: {
        path: '/trains/:idTrain',
        name: 'Train details',
        viewName: 'TRAIN_DETAILS',
    },
```

routingManager.tsx file looks like:

```
const TrainsAlertsListScreen = lazy(() =>
    import('@nevomo/trains').then((module) => ({
        default: module.TrainsAlertsList,
    }))

const TrainDetailsScreen = lazy(() =>
    import('@nevomo/trains').then((module) => ({
        default: module.TrainDetailsScreen,
    }))
);
<ProtectedRoute
                    requiredRoles={[
                        ROLES.vehicleOperator,
                        ROLES.vehicleAnalyst,
                    ]}
                    isAuth={isLogin}
                    exact
                    path={[
                        Routes.Trains.path,
                        Routes.TrainsMap.path,
                        Routes.TrainDetails.path,
                        Routes.TrainHistory.path,
                        Routes.TrainService.path,
                        Routes.TrainWheels.path,
                        Routes.TrainsAlertsList.path,
                    ]}
                >
);

<ProtectedRoute
                            requiredRoles={[
                                ROLES.vehicleOperator,
                                ROLES.vehicleAnalyst,
                            ]}
                            isAuth={isLogin}
                            path={Routes.TrainsAlertsList.path}
                            Component={TrainsAlertsListScreen}
                            exact
                        />
                        <ProtectedRoute
                            requiredRoles={[
                                ROLES.vehicleOperator,
                                ROLES.vehicleAnalyst,
                            ]}
                            isAuth={isLogin}
                            path={Routes.TrainDetails.path}
                            Component={TrainDetailsScreen}
                            exact
                        />
```

index.ts with all exports:

```
export * from './lib/trains';
export * from './lib/components/map/map';
export * from './views/train-details/train-details';
export * from './views/train-history/train-history';
export * from './views/train-service/train-service';
export * from './views/train-wheels/train-wheels';
export * from './views/train-wheels/components/train-wheels-details/train-wheels-details';
export * from './views/train-wheels/components/train-wheels-faults/train-wheels-faults';
export * from './lib/components/trains-alerts-list/trains-alerts-list';
```

And component:

```
import { Toolbar } from '@nevomo/common-components';
import { FC } from 'react';

export const TrainsAlertsList: FC = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Toolbar />
            <div>działa</div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Can You please look at it and let me know what is causing that TrainDetailsScreen is rendered although it's not called ? And how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both these components match and render on the `Routes.TrainDetails.path` (*i.e. `"/trains/:idTrain"`*) path. Since both are being rendered then I'll assume you are rendering your routes into a `Router` and *not* within a `Switch`. If you are wanting only a single route to match and be rendered render them into the `Switch` component.

[Switch](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch)

The `Switch` differs from the `Router` in that a `Router` ***inclusively*** renders all matching routes by path whereas the `Switch` ***exclusively*** renders only the first match. In the `Switch` path order and specificity matter! You want to order the paths from more specific paths to less specific, so matching and rendering can work properly.

`'/trains/alerts-list'` is *more* specific than `'/trains/:idTrain'` and should be rendered higher/before.

Example:

```
<Router>

  ...

  <Switch>

    .... other more specific "/trains/alerts-list/...." routes

    <ProtectedRoute
      requiredRoles={[
        ROLES.vehicleOperator,
        ROLES.vehicleAnalyst,
      ]}
      isAuth={isLogin}
      path={Routes.TrainsAlertsList.path} // '/trains/alerts-list'
      Component={TrainsAlertsListScreen}
    />

    .... other more specific "/trains/...." routes

    <ProtectedRoute
      requiredRoles={[
        ROLES.vehicleOperator,
        ROLES.vehicleAnalyst,
      ]}
      isAuth={isLogin}
      path={Routes.TrainDetails.path}     // '/trains/:idTrain'
      Component={TrainDetailsScreen}
    />

    .... other less routes

  </Switch>

  ...

</Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

These 2 routes match the same thing: `/trains/alerts-list` is the same as `trains/:id`. You should use the `exact` attribute in the `Route` component (This is not the case if you are using react-router v6) or change one of them. Try with `trains/:id/details`

```
TrainsAlertsList: {
        path: '/trains/alerts-list',
        name: 'Trains alerts list',
        viewName: 'TRAINS_ALERTS_LIST',
    },
TrainDetails: {
        path: '/trains/:idTrain',
        name: 'Train details',
        viewName: 'TRAIN_DETAILS',
    },
```